# Error 500 when calling asmx service from javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, asmx

I am calling a .net 2.0 asmx service using javascript and servicereference. When I call the service in the test environment and locally, everything works fine. In production I get an error 500. I don't see any errors in the event log or displayed anywhere.

If I hit the web service directly then I receive the json formatted data. If I call the web service from javascript using the servicereference then I get the error 500.

I think this might be related to a size limitation since I can reduce the number of datapoints and the data is returned through javascript correctly.

I have tried increasing the maxRequestLength in httpRuntime but that doesn't have any affect. Is there some setting that I am missing?

If you view this page: http://bit.ly/NXBFpD you will see that data is returned without an error.

If you view this page and watch the calls being made in firebug you'll see that the same page as above is called, but an error 500 is returned. http://bit.ly/NXBPO1

This is the code-behind on the page being called:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).Services.Add(new ServiceReference("/Services/FusionService.asmx"));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the js code calling the service:

```
function GetGeometries(sw, ne, metro) {
    FusionService.GetGeometries(sw.lat(), sw.lng(), ne.lat(), ne.lng(), metro, drawMap);
}
```

This is the service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class FusionService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
private string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query";

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetGeometries(decimal southWestLat, decimal southWestLng, decimal northEastLat, decimal northEastLng, string metro)
{
    try
    {
        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string key = string.Format("Geometry-{0}", metro);

        var geometryData = HttpContext.Current.Cache[key] as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(geometryData))
        {
            var deserialized = jss.Deserialize<GeometryData>(geometryData);
            return jss.Serialize(deserialized);
        }

        var query = "SELECT name, geometry, FranchiseI, latitude, longitude, STATE FROM " +
                    "1JNOz_lhP1B8oCzeNLBm8u5k6ezdRDKtM-NBD8 where ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, RECTANGLE(LATLNG("
                    + southWestLat + "," + southWestLng + "), LATLNG(" + northEastLat + "," + northEastLng + ")))";

        var requestString = url + "?sql=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query) + "&key=AIzaSyCXLd2VlvZ0FNLbgMKsfSq7Uvp3IDwa";

        var request = WebRequest.Create(requestString) as HttpWebRequest;

        using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            json = json.Replace("NaN", "\"\"");

            HttpContext.Current.Cache[key] = json;
            var deserialized = jss.Deserialize<GeometryData>(json);

            return jss.Serialize(deserialized);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You're going to have to check your server logs to figure out what's going wrong.  A 500 error means that the server side code failed, and without seeing what the code is nobody is going to be able to figure out your problem.

Comment: I checked the server logs and there are no error messages. I updated my post with the relevant code and some example urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was being caused by a limit in the size that can be serialized by JSON. I needed to add this to my web.config.

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <!--The Following lines value should be true in production server-->
        <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="false" enableCaching="true" />
<webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000000">
    </jsonSerialization>
  </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the URL from the browser on the server and you'll likely see the contents of the error. Alternatively - change your web.config, so you can see the actual error from a client browser as well:

Set:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

This will allow you to track down the issue and resolve it!